# PDF "saving" Rotation?

Tags: java, pdf, rotation

I am using the lowagie API to read PDFs into my Java application and edit them programatically. There are only 3 PDFs I'm passing in at the moment, so I can edit them as necessary before passing them in. However, I have one PDF that I originally received with a 90 degree rotation. At first, I just tried rotating it to the orientation I wanted in OSX Preview, saving it, and then passing it to the code, but the output PDF is back to the rotation of the original. I noticed that this happens no matter what rotation I give the original, and I've verified that the rotation persists after I save the file by reopening it in preview.

I suspect that there is some metadata that keeps track of the original rotation and that the PDF reverts to this rotation when reading the file, but I'm not sure how to check this. I did look up an example of rotating programmatically with the lowagie API, but for some reason this creates new issues that prevent me from programmatically adding text to the PDF, and I would rather just read in a properly rotated PDF to begin with rather than try to solve this problem and further complicate my code. Here is the code I currently use to read in PDFs and add text:

```
PdfReader reader = PDFHelper._pdfReaderForTemplate(templateName);
float leftMargin = 36f;
float rightMargin = leftMargin;
float topMargin = 36f;
float bottomMargin = 36f;
Rectangle pageSize = PageSize.LETTER.rotate();
Document pdfDocument = new Document(pageSize, leftMargin, rightMargin, topMargin, bottomMargin);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter pdfWriter = null;
pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument, baos);
pdfDocument.open();
PdfContentByte cb = pdfWriter.getDirectContent();
PdfImportedPage sheetTemplate = pdfWriter.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
pdfDocument.newPage();
float startY = pageSize.getTop() - topMargin;
float y = startY;
float width = pageSize.getWidth() - leftMargin;
cb.addTemplate(sheetTemplate, 0f, 0f);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    float eventX = 0f;
    float eventY = 0f;
    float nameX = 0f;
    float nameY = 0f;
    if(PDFKey.equals("PDF1")){
        eventX = (width / 3f * (i + 1)) - 96;
        nameX = (width / 3f * i) + 41 - (4 * (i - 1));
        eventY = y - 23f;
        nameY = y - 38f;
     } else  if(PDFKey.equals("PDF2")){
        eventX = (width / 3f * (i + 1)) - 96;
        nameX = (width / 3f * i) + 41 - (4 * (i - 1));
        eventY = y + 3;
        nameY = y - 11f;
     } else if(PDFKey.equals("PDF3")){
        eventX = (width / 3f * (i + 1)) - 83;
        nameX = (width / 3f * i) + 44 - (2 * (i - 1));
        eventY = y - 24f;
        nameY = y - 38f;
     }
     cb.beginText();
     cb.setFontAndSize(PDFHelper.NexusSansOTBold, 8);
     cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, event.id().toString(), eventX, eventY, 0f);
     cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, event.eventName(), nameX, nameY, 0f);
     cb.endText();
     }
pdfDocument.close();
```

Am I correct in suspecting that PDFs "save" their original rotation somehow? If so, how can I permanently rotate my PDF in such a way that it doesn't output rotated back after running this code? If not, what are some other possible culprits for the rotation?

EDIT: I am investigating using PDFCopy as another route to solve my problem. However, when following examples I run into a new problem. Following [these](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-6) examples, I came up with this new code:

```
...
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(pdfDocument, baos);
pdfDocument.open();
PdfImportedPage page = copy.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
PdfCopy.PageStamp stamp = copy.createPageStamp(page);
float startY = pageSize.getTop() - topMargin;
float y = startY;
float width = pageSize.getWidth() - leftMargin;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    float eventX = 0f;
    float eventY = 0f;
    float nameX = 0f;
    float nameY = 0f;
    if(PDFKey.equals("PDF1")){
        eventX = (width / 3f * (i + 1)) - 96;
        nameX = (width / 3f * i) + 41 - (4 * (i - 1));
        eventY = y - 23f;
        nameY = y - 38f;
     } else if(PDFKey.equals("PDF2")){
         eventX = (width / 3f * (i + 1)) - 96;
         nameX = (width / 3f * i) + 41 - (4 * (i - 1));
         eventY = y + 3;
         nameY = y - 11f;
     } else if(PDFKey.equals("PDF3")){
         eventX = (width / 3f * (i + 1)) - 83;
         nameX = (width / 3f * i) + 44 - (2 * (i - 1));
         eventY = y - 24f;
         nameY = y - 38f;
     }
     ColumnText.showTextAligned(stamp.getUnderContent(), Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(event.id().toString()), eventX, eventY, 0f);
     ColumnText.showTextAligned(stamp.getUnderContent(), Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(event.eventName()), nameX, nameY, 0f);
     }
copy.addPage(page);
pdfDocument.close();
reader.close();
```

This solves the rotation issue. However, I'm not sure how to set the font size in this case, which I need to do in order to get the output I want. In the previous version, I created a PdfWriter using the PdfDocument and then a PdfContentByte from the PdfWriter, but in the second case, I'm using a PdfCopy for the actual output PDF rather than the original PdfDocument, and I don't see a way to create a PdfWriter using a PdfCopy. In fact, every example of creating an altered PDF using PdfCopy shows a PageStamp being used to make changes rather than a PdfWriter, and static methods from ColumnText rather than nonstatic methods from a PdfContentByte. This means that there is no PdfContentByte for me to set the font size of, so I'm not sure where to include the font size.

Also, my original code will work if I have a way to rotate the PDF before it reaches my code without it keeping track of the fact that the page was rotated. In other words, rotating and saving the PDF in an editing program is not enough-- I need a PDF that is a rotated version of the original, but is treated by the code as if it was created with that orientation to begin with.

Comment: **a** *"the lowagie API"* - I wouldn't be surprised if Bruno will tell you what he thinks of that. For now it suffices to say that that is an ancient iText version. **b** yes, rotation is a page level information but your code drops all that information except resources and content streams. Switch to `PdfCopy` with page stamps to copy and manipulate complete pages.

Comment: Is there a PDF editor that will let me change the rotation information for the page? I'm having trouble finding one-- everything I search for just shows me how to rotate and save and the file.

Comment: What's the difference for you?

Comment: It's more straightforward for me if I don't have to worry about the rotations the page has undergone before the PDFs are handled in my code, since rotating and saving a PDF before this point leads to a situation where the rotation gets undone. I'm looking into using PDFcopy which preserves the rotation, but it would be much faster if I could just pass in a PDF that was normally oriented and had no saved page rotations to begin with. Since rotating in an editor always saves the rotation, I have no way to get an initial PDF file that won't end up rotated incorrectly upon losing this rotation.

Comment: Your `PdfCopy` variant looks better. Concerning the font size: you add `Phrase` instances. When creating a `Phrase` you can not only provide text but also a font which in turn can be created with a font size of your choice.